# I am new to php and request you to help me in how to echo array [i] values in php. Also I need total for the $Amount

Tags: php, mysql

submitting the values of $Date, $Cashier and $Amount to phpmyadmin are successful and are being stored in the database. However when I want to the echo all the $Amount values and the total of $Amount, I am not able to do so. Please kindly suggest or fix this code. If I use [i], I was able to get the count of $Amount but I want to get the display of $Amount values and the total of all the $Amount values.

```
<?php

include_once('config.php');

$userData = count($_POST["Amount"]);

if ($userData > 0) {

for ($i=0; $i < $userData; $i++) { 

//if (trim($_POST['name'] != '') && trim($_POST['email'] != ''))
    
$Date   = $_POST["Date"];

$Cashier  = $_POST["Cashier"];

$Amount  = $_POST["Amount"][$i];

$query  = "INSERT INTO sl_vou (Date,Cashier,Amount) VALUES ('$Date','$Cashier','$Amount')";

$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

//$getreport=mysqli_query($conn," SELECT  Date,Cashier, SUM(Amount)");

//$result_report=mysqli_fetch_array($getreport);
    
    }
}

    
echo "******************";

echo "<br>";

echo "Date:";

echo $Date;

echo "<br>";

echo "Cashier:";

echo $Cashier;

echo "<br>";

echo "<br>";

echo $userData[0][$i]."/".$userData[1][$i]."/".$userData[2][$i] ."<br/>";

print_r($userData);

echo "- values posted successfully";

echo "<br>";

echo "<br>";

?>


<html>

<script>

function myFunction() {

alert("Vouchers Collection Completed - Redirecting to dashboard!..............");

}

</script>

<form action="dashboard.php" method="post">

<button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>

</form>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not display the values inside the first loop, where you insert them into the database? I presume your `print_r()` shows the correct data? (ETA it won't, as @ajCary said below)

Comment: You also echo "values inserted correctly" without doing any checks to see whether the queries worked or not. This is a confusing message for your user. You should check what is in `$results` to see whether the query gave an error or not. You should also read up on prepared statements rather than concatenating values into queries, for many reasons.

Comment: `$userData` is getting set to the count of elements in $_POST["Amount"] - so this is either an integer or FALSE, and not an array unless I'm missing something

Comment: @ajCary indeed, a nice confusing variable name.

Comment: @droopsnoot my print_r() is showing the count of the values, but here I want to display the Values of the $Amount and the Total of $Amount

Comment: the $Amount is the itenary field where a Cashier can input n number of values in a day. I am trying to show all the values that has been entered and finally the total of the $Amount

Comment: Please refrain from interpolating variables directly into SQL queries, especially if they are unprocessed user input. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

For more information, please read this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php (MYSQLI flavor)

Comment: @TimSparrow Noted, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with the line

```
    echo $userData[0][$i]."/".$userData[1][$i]."/".$userData[2][$i] ."<br/>";
```

however try replacing the line `print_r($userData);` with

```
    $Total = 0;
    foreach($_POST["Amount"] as $thisAmount) {
        echo $thisAmount . "<br>";
        $Total += $thisAmount;
    }
    echo $Total;
```

Hopefully this, with the other suggestions, gets you a bit further.

Comment: @ajCarry Thank you very much indeed for solving my puzzle, I will sort the remaining code as suggested and change the $userData..Thank you once Again ''AJCARRY''

Comment: My pleasure :-)  ..although please note the comment from @droopsnoot  about using prepared statements. Doing so is the best way to prevent SQL injection attacks, or any accidental bad characters messing up your database query!!

Comment: @ajCarry will definetly look into the suggestions from both of you, Cheers..